# Regular Expression for particular format

Tags: java, regex

Need one Regular expression for finding the below format in Java

```
ABC.CDB.ASD[0].QWE[0]
```

Tried this: `\\b\\w{3}+\\.\\w{3}+\\.\\w{3}\\[.+?\\]+\\.\\w\\[.+?\\]+\\b`

but failed.

Without boundaries it is working if I give the specific length for the last array like:

```
  \\w{3}+\\.\\w{3}+\\.\\w{3}\\[.+?\\]+\\.\\w{3}\\[.+?\\]+
```

Want boundaries and last word without length.

Can any body help please?

Comment: Give full Java code which shows exactly *how* you used these. For example, all the backslashes should be doubled if they are used as Java String literals.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have too many "+" symbol.
The right regexp should be the following:
`\w{3}\.\w{3}\.\w{3}\[\d+\]\.\w{3}\[\d+\]`

Why have you put "+" after "\w{3}"?

Answer (score 1):

I tried this one and it works. 
You can remove the small letters **a-z** if you want to restrict it to only capital letters.

```
([a-zA-Z]{3}.){2}[a-zA-Z]+\[\d+\].[a-zA-Z]+\[\d+\]$
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the trailing `\b`. `\b` means a "word boundary" - between a word and a non-word. Unless your target is followed by a word char, you won't get a match. ie the input would have to look like:

```
ABC.CDB.ASD[0].QWE[0]A
```

Also the trailing `+` after the `]` seem unnecessary. Try this:

```
\\w{3}+\\.\\w{3}+\\.\\w{3}\\[.+?\\]\\.\\w\\[.+?\\]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this may help:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w{3}\\.\\w{3}\\.\\w{3}\\[\\d{1}\\]\\.\\w{3}\\[\\d{1}\\]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `+` after the last `\\w`:

```
\\b\\w{3}+\\.\\w{3}+\\.\\w{3}\\[.+?\\]+\\.\\w+\\[.+?\\]+
//                                    here __^
```

IFAIK, there're no needs of `\\b` at the end.